# How do force merge everything i have locally into the remote master?

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

The issue is that a team member had by mistake created a separate branch (main branch being master) called "Head". "Head" has the latest code which i now want to over-write to the master (since it is up-to-date with all the code).

When i try to perform "Merge Head into master" i get an error saying "unrelated branches". I searched on so and found out that i would need to pull the branch ("Head") locally and then push (or force-push) it to the remote "master" branch to merge the code.

I used the following command:
`git fetch && git checkout Head` and checked it out (cloned it) to local. Now when i try to push it shows that i am 17 commits behind and 3 changes to push.

How do force merge everything i have locally into the remote master ?

Thanks

[image: SourceTree]

**EDIT**

I did what [das-g](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31760214/1221203) told but it seems that the only change i see in remote is that the `Head` branch is deleted. The code changes which were originally there in `Head` has vanished (or lost!!!). I can see the tags and history but it seems the changes are deleted forever!!!

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I would pull and merge into the real (server) branch. Then move the local head to point to the server/origin head. This way nothing is 'forced'. Git is like a tree, not a highway.

Comment: Please give me a working solution in commands instead of directions. I want to come out of this mess!!

Comment: _Re: Edit about apparently lost changes:_ Hu? In your second Screenshot, I can still see the same revisions, just the local `Head` branch is gone. (Have you deleted it although the merge was aborted due to missing commit message?) `git checkout -b Head origin/Head` should restore your local `Head` branch (because the remote `Head` branch is still pointing at the right revision `09298ea`, as far as I can see from your screenshot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems from your screenshot and from error message that `master` and `Head` do not have any common ancestors. If I understood you correctly,

- you want the tip of `master` to have the current content of `Head` (and *exactly* that content, not `Head`'s content merged with the content of `master`),
- but you want to have both branch's history preserved in `master`'s ancestry. (Thus `git checkout master; git reset --hard Head` isn't an option.)

You can either rebase the `Head` commits on top of master, as [VonC suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31760116/674064), to produce a linear history, at the price that `Head`'s commits will be re-written.

If you want to preserve `Head`'s commits exactly as they are, you can do a somewhat obscure merge:

1. First, make sure your local `master` is up-to-date (from your screenshot, it doesn't seem to be)

   ```
   git checkout master
   git merge --ff-only origin/master
   ```
2. The actual merge

   ```
   git checkout Head
   git merge --strategy ours master
   ```
3. Get the merge commit into `master`

   ```
   git checkout master
   git merge --ff-only Head
   ```
4. You'll probably want to get rid of the strangely named `Head` branch, now

   ```
   git branch -D Head
   ```
5. and to get everything (including the branch deletion) onto the remote repo

   ```
   git push origin master :Head # should not need a force-push as no commits are discarded on the remote site
   ```

Comment: That is looking quite detailed, a good alternative to my answer. +1

Comment: when i execute `git merge --strategy ours master` i get to a vim. How to properly type commit msg and go ahead?

Comment: when i execute `git merge --strategy ours master` i get to a vim. I pressed `ZZ` and i got  a msg `error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.` So i executed `git commit -m "Merge"` and proceeded but i still see that the remote has code from the earlier branch and not this current branch. Only different is `Head` is deleted.

Comment: I have no idea what `ZZ` does in vim. For merges, I'm usually happy with the message that git already populated the editor with, so I just type `:x[ENTER]`, which is short for `:wq[ENTER]` (or `:w[ENTER]` followed by `:q[ENTER]`), i.e. write (=save) and quit (=close the editor).

Answer (score 2):

First, do not call a branch "Head": that is very close from [HEAD, which references the "current commit"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/964927/6309).

You can rename it easily: `git branch -m Head Tip`

Regarding the unrelate branch situation, you can try and cherry-pick it on top of master:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b tmp
git cherry-pick Tip~2 Tip~1 Tip
git branch -f Tip tmp
git checkout Tip
```

(the [`rebase --onto` option is a bit more complex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9091843/6309))

Once everything looks ok locally, you updtate the new branch name on the remote repo:

```
git push origin --set-upstream Tip
git push origin :Head
```

Comment: The branch "Head" is there in the remote repo. Do i need to rename in the remote repo too ? Can you make the commands bit more specific to the screenshot i provided. Thanks,i am noob when it comes to git.

Comment: @Nezam those commands are specific to your screenshot. It won't rename the remote branch though. For that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4754132/6309

Comment: @Nezam yes (if you have renamed your branch first): you cherry-pick from the oldest to the newest.

Comment: @Nezam If anything "vanishes", type "git reflog", and look for commit 09298ea: do a `git checkout -B Tip 09298ea` and your branch gets back where it was initially.

Comment: Thanks!! Ok now i have a new branch called `Tip` and it has the updated code. How to push this up to the remote `master` now. So that the remove master has only single branch and this updated code?

Comment: @Nezam Before pushing anywhere, did you replay your Tip commit on top of your local master branch as I mention in the answer? You will push only when the situation is ok locally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84879/discussion-between-nezam-and-vonc).